# Where is my git repository after pushing through an ssh tunnel?

Tags: git, ssh

I've set my router at home to do port forwarding via SSH.  I've succesfully cloned git repositories via:

```
git clone git+ssh://user@localhost:1234/repos local_repos
```

and then working locally, I can `push` and `pull` without trouble.

Now I'm in the situation where I created a project locally and I want to put it on my home machine.  This is what I tried.  On the home machine:

```
cd && mkdir new-project && mkdir new-project/.git
cd !$ && git --bare init
```

On the local machine:

```
mkdir new-project && cd new-project
git init
... (add, commit etc.)
git remote add origin origin git+ssh:/user@localhost:1234/home/user/new-project
git push origin master --tags
```

After giving my credentials, it seems to work happily.  But if look on the home machine, I see nothing.  A `git status` in `/home/user/new-project` yields an error.

Question:  **Where did my stuff get pushed too? (Or, what got pushed?)**
Secondly:  **How can I achieve this when my tunnel is 'one way' so to speak?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are working with a *bare* repository. You have to `cd .git ; git status` to see the status. See [git ready](http://www.gitready.com/advanced/2009/02/01/push-to-only-bare-repositories.html) for some related discussion.

Comment: Thanks for the link, that explained it perfectly.  But as an aside, `cd .git ; git status`, as the error message implies only works in a work tree.

Answer (score 0):

If the error is "fatal: This operation must be run in a work tree", that's normal for bare repositories. A better test would be to try cloning the repository.

Comment: There's no error.  According to the client side, the push works.  When I log in to the server I see nothing.

Comment: you said git status yields an error.  And it's normal to see nothing in a bare repo, depending on your definition of 'nothing'.  Have you tried cloning from it?

Comment: I misunderstood; hind sight allows me to map your thought process correctly.  I didn't know what a bare repository was.  And yes, if I clone from it does work.  Thanks for the tip.